# Given $a\equiv x\pmod p$ and $b\equiv y\pmod q$, can we deduce a congruence relating $a,b,c,y$ modulo $pq$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Assume that \begin{align*} a &\equiv x \pmod p  \\ b &\equiv y\pmod q.\end{align*}

Does this imply an equation involving the numbers $a,b,x,y$ modulo $pq$? One possible example would be 
$$ab \equiv xy\mod pq$$

Comment: Not quite. Take $a = 0$, $x = p$, $b = 1$, and $y = q+1$. Then your suggestion gives
$$ 0 \equiv (q+1)p \bmod pq$$
which doesn't have to be true! However, if you avoid picking anything that reduces to 0..? (Also, I'm guessing $p$ and $q$ are primes?)

Comment: I don't think you can do better than $$ab\equiv (x\mod q)(y\mod p)\mod pq$$
since the value of $x\mod p$ and $y\mod q$ don't tell you much about $x\mod q$ and $y\mod p$.

Comment: Well, you have $$(a-x)(b-y) \equiv 0 \mod pq$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an equivalent question: given that $(a - x)$ is a multiple of $p$ and $(b - y)$ is a multiple of $q$, can we conclude that something is a multiple of $pq$? The answer is yes: $(a - x)(b - y)$, $(a - x)q$, and $p(b - y)$ all must be multiples of $pq$. So, among other things, we have:

$$\begin{align*}(a - x)(b - y) &\equiv 0\phantom{0} \pmod{pq}\\
aq &\equiv xq \pmod {pq}\\
pb &\equiv py \pmod{pq}.\end{align*}$$

The first equation might look nicer if we multiply it out:

$$ab + xy \equiv ay + xb \pmod{pq}.$$

Answer (score 1):

There is similiar law
$$a \equiv b\pmod n \\c \equiv d\pmod n $$
imply
$$ac \equiv bd\pmod n \\a+c \equiv b+d\pmod n $$